# Spring Boot Remote GC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, garbage-collection

While running spring boot application I was told that while not precising that the current aplication is going to be working using a production environment, some ports are being opened, also allowing people to perform such actions from the outside of the code, just by making requests to start a GC on the machine where our application sits. Is it possible to do so in the basic spring boot program without any properties set up? What needs to be done take care of it and disallow people running GC on your application?

Comment: "*while not precising that the production is going to be working on production*" Sorry, I presume English is not your first language, and that's ok, but this doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Please reiterate your question and make it more specific. Also mention what you tried if you tried something which didn't work as expected.

Comment: Maybe someone was referring to JMX which is part of some Java Virtual Machines which you can access e.g. with (j)visualvm https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html

Comment: Or they may have been referring to jolokia, see: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.M2/reference/html/production-ready-jmx.html